# Separating string into two Python array's

Tags: python

I'm trying to split a string of words into two lists of words using the query below. The string up until 'a' should go into begin, and the rest into remainder. But the while loop somehow keeps running regardless of the fact that begin already contains 'a'. Thanks a lot for your help!

```
random_string = 'hello this is a test string'
split = {}
split = random_string.split()
begin = []
remainder = []

while 'a' not in begin:
for word in split:
    storage = word
    begin.append(storage)


print(begin)
```

Comment: The conditional `while 'a' not in begin` is only checked on each iteration of that outer loop (so in this case, twice, before the `for` loop and after).  When you nested `for word in split:` that entire loop will complete before the `while 'a'` condition is checked again. You should have added the condition to check if `'a'` is in `begin` inside of the for loop.

Comment: Could you add the output you expect? What other cases could you encounter? (What would you want if there was several separator elements?)

Comment: So I intend to split one large text file into smaller text files. I was trying now two for loops to split a string into three pieces as follows: 
`random_string = 'hello this is a test string, now I will <d> make it longer'
split = {}
split = random_string.split()
begin = []
part_2 = []
remainder = []


for word in split:
    if 'a' in begin:
        remainder.append(word)
    else:
        begin.append(word)

for word in remainder:
    if '<d>' in remainder:
        remainder.append(word)
    else:
        part_2.append(word)

print(begin)
print(part_2)
print(remainder)`

Answer (score 1):

So your problem here is that the while loop condition is checked after the for loop has completed. Essentially this is what happens

1. 'a' is not in begin
2. Loop through the split and add every word to begin
3. check is 'a' is in begin

You could try something like:

```
for word in split:
    if 'a' in begin:
        remainder.append(word)
    else:
        begin.append(word)
```

where the 'a' condition is checked on every iteration of the loop or follow the slicing techniques listed in other answers

Comment: this one is perfect! Just what I was looking for. Just a follow up. If i'd want to split a larger text piece into 3 or 4, would I be able to run it like this? 
for word in split:
    if 'a' in begin:
        remainder.append(word)
    else:
        begin.append(word)

Comment: I wasn't done typing, what I meant was using an extra for loop to split the remainder as follows: 

`random_string = 'hello this is a test string, now I will <d> make it longer'
split = {}
split = random_string.split()
begin = []
part_2 = []
remainder = []


for word in split:
    if 'a' in begin:
        remainder.append(word)
    else:
        begin.append(word)

for word in remainder:
    if '<d>' in remainder:
        remainder.append(word)
    else:
        part_2.append(word)

print(begin)
print(part_2)
print(remainder)
`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, **just two lines**. one to get the words with 'a', another to get words without out 'a'.

```
random_string = 'hello this is a test string, tap task'

begin = [x for x in random_string.split(' ') if 'a' in x]
remainder = [x for x in random_string.split(' ') if 'a' not in x]

print begin, remainder
```

will print.

```
['a', 'tap', 'task']
['hello', 'this', 'is', 'test', 'string,']
```

Comment: nice split, but it doesn't add each part of the string into a list. How would I do that?

Comment: It does my friend, because its inside a list already. the contents of the list are generated by the split. and condition is checked on each element of the split. I will try to get some documentation for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using slices and index, there is no need to run a loop for catching the 'a':

```
random_string = 'hello this is a test string'
split = random_string.split(' ')
index = split.index('a') + 1
array_1 = split[:index]
array_2 = split[index:]

print(array_1, array_2)
```

Comment: Errr this will create lists of letters :( my bad, using `split(' ')` instead of converting to a list will do the trick right at the beginning

Comment: Is there a way to keep the words in the array's? This returns two arrays with  all the characters split into pieces.

Comment: Just fixed it (see my coment) :-P sorry about the previous one

Answer (score 0):

Just [slice](http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/) the list you get by spliting your string :

## To take the sentence until a specific word :

```
>>>words = "one two three four"
>>>words.split()[:words.split().index("three")+1]
['one', 'two', 'three']
>>>words.split()[words.split().index("three")+1:]
['four']
```

## To take half the sentence :

(Your post seemed ambiguous to me about what you wanted.)

```
>>>words = "one two three four"
>>>words.split()[:len(words.split())//2]
['one', 'two']
>>>words.split()[len(words.split())//2:]
['three', 'four']
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking at `.index` method of array and there is no need of loop.

```
random_string = 'hello this is a test string'

split = random_string.split()

begin = []
remainder = []
index = split.index('a')

begin = split[:index] 
remainder = split[index:]

print(begin)
print(remainder)
```

Code snippet above will print:

```
['hello', 'this', 'is']
['a', 'test', 'string']
```

Answer (score -2):

Use builtin string routines:

```
>>> str = 'hello this is a test string'
>>> begin, end str.split('a')
['hello this is ', ' test string']
>>> begin_words = begin.split()
['hello', 'this', 'is']
>>> end_words = end.split()
['test', 'string']
```

The default of `split` is to split on whitespace, but as you can see, it works with other strings as well.

Comment: This solution doesn't keep the separator.